# How to select object in scene with button in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have a scene. And this scene has 3 objects(spheres and cube). On the right of the scene, I have a div element (**id** = "rightMenu").
I want to add buttons to *rightMenu* dynamically. One of the button name sphere the other button name is cube and last one is sphere1.
And when I click the sphere button, the sphere in the scene is highlighting.
Here is my code:

```
<body>

<div id="Button-area">
</div>
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    var projector = new THREE.Projector();
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
    cube.position.set(-9,3,0);
    scene.add(cube);

    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 20, 20);
    var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x7777ff});
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere.position.set(20,0,2);
    scene.add(sphere);

    var sphere2Geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 20, 20);
    var sphere2Material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x77fff});
    var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(sphere2Geometry, sphere2Material);
    sphere2.position.set(40,-3,4);
    scene.add(sphere2);

    camera.position.set(-30,40,30);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(-40, 60, -10);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    render();

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

    }

    var projector = new THREE.Projector();

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        vector = vector.unproject(camera);

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([sphere, sphere2, cube]);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            intersects[0].object.material.transparent = true;
            intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.1;
        }
      }

    }
    window.onload = init();   
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui)? many examples on Three.js website use this tool.

Comment: Actually, in my real program, I have more than 1000 object. Can it be applied to so many objects? @Craig.Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an option how you can do this.

You can create a menu button and an object in the scene at the same time, giving both of them the same name and then, in  the `click` event of the button, read its name and look for the object with the same name.

```
sceneObjects = [];
```

when you create an object, push it in this array:

```
sceneObjects.push(mesh);
```

and then, when you click the button, you will look for the object:

```
function onClick(event) {
  var name = event.target.name.trim(); // get the name of the button
  sceneObjects.forEach(function(obj) { // loop through array of objects
    obj.material.emissive.setRGB(0, 0, 0); // reset to default (black)
    if (obj.name == name) obj.material.emissive.setRGB(.5, .5, 0); // highlighting
  });
}
```

It's up to you, how you will realize highlighting of objects, I used just emissive color.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/hq3gu6jr/) example.

Comment: Yes, this is I want. Thank you very much. This was very big problem for me. Thank you :)